# Next in array and index out of bounds

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

What would be best practice and solution for checking for "Index out of bounds" The following solution works but feels quite hacky. Is there any better alternatives?

```
public void nextPerson(int index){ //Index is the current location in the arraylist
    try{
        System.out.println(thePeople.get(index++));
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("At the end");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that by having a local variable to keep track of Arraylist index. I was able to instead have 2 methods for handling the moving thoughtout the ArrayList. With one for the current position for outputting.

```
if(arrayPosition < thePeople.size() - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Java is pass-by-value. That means that if you pass the "index" variable to the function, the external variable won't be affected by the changes performed inside the function.

So you have to keep the index var class-scoped, like the List...

```
public void nextPerson(){ 
    if (index>=0 && index<thePeople.size())
        System.out.println(thePeople.get(index++));
    } else {
        System.out.println("At the end");
    }
}
```

OR to pass it AND return it

```
    public int nextPerson(int index){ 
        if (index>=0 && index<thePeople.size())
            System.out.println(thePeople.get(index++));
        } else {
            System.out.println("At the end");
        }
        return index;
    }
```

The same would be for the previouPerson, just use `index--`;

By the way, if you keep the index in a consumer Class, outside of this object, you could get the whole List and iterate over it in the consumer class...

Comment: With your solution, what would be the correct way to have a previousPerson method?

Comment: Exactly the same but with `index--`... i suggest you to post a bigger extract of your code, to see if it's possible to redesign it a little bit

Comment: My orignial thought was to use `index--` but it didn't work.     `private ArrayList<People> thePeople;` I just have a basic constructor in which i add them to the array with.